# Why can we use global variable before assignment in Python?

Tags: python

Why does following code work well in Python?

```
def show():
    print(a)
a = 1
show()
```

I think if we use show function before assignment (`a = 1`),
undefined error for `a` should be output.
However, beyond my expectation the code above works well....

Comment: The reference to `a` in your function doesn't take place until the function is *called*.  Since `a` is set before `show()` is called, `a` is in the global namespace when `show` tries to access it.

Comment: You *can't*. Try to actually use the `show` function before assignment and it will error. Your code uses it *after*

Answer (score 2):

The content of the function "show" runs only after "show" function is being called.
You're calling "show" function after you're assigning variable a value (a=1), and that's why an error is not being thrown.

The code run as follows:

1. Defining the function "show" but not running its content
2. Setting value of variable a to 1
3. Calling the function "show"
4. Printing the value of variable a, which is 1

Answer (score 2):

What a function definition like the one in your code actually means:

```
def show():
    print(a)
```

It defines a function that, when executed, will print the value named `a`. And because that name is not defined in the function itself, it will refer to a global variable (or cause an error if the name isn't defined when the function is executed).

Your code then goes on, after the function definition, to define `a`:

```
a = 1
```

And finally, the function you defined is actually executed, this is the first time the code in the function will actually run, and because you defined `a` beforehand, it will correctly print "1".

```
show()
```